# Routines intermittently not being executed on Apache Beam code

Tags: google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam

I have an Apache Beam pipeline written on Java. I'm with a problem that some routines are not being executed on all instances of that pipeline.

Those routines are as simple as logging messages or excluding a file in GCS. They are all put to run after the following code:

```
p.run.waitUntilFinish();
```

Somehow we think this is related to Cloud Dataflow, which is the runner we identified the issue. We could not reproduce on DirectRunner and we did not try any other runner other than those.

I suppose this has something to do with the nature of distributed processing, but I could not identify the root cause so far. The latest Apache Beam sample codes have a try/catch block wrapping `p.run()...` which made me think of possible uncaught Exceptions being thrown that could cause the issue.

Thoughts?

Comment: Its unclear from your question what is not executing. Are you trying to say that you have a ParDo that doesn't execute at all or are you trying to get a ParDo to execute on every machine?

Comment: As I said, they are things like "logging messages or excluding a file in GCS", in other words, regular Java code not related to Apache Beam's SDK.

Comment: Please include a representative snippet of your code and describe the expected behavior and the actual observed behavior.